# Will I encounter any problems if I change the App switcher to another using CCSM. 15.10 64 bit

Tags: compiz, application-switcher, ccsm

I want to change the switcher via CCSM but I'm not sure this would be wise to do without consulting. Every time I've messed around with Compiz I had ran into troubles.

If you want to stick to an specific case let's say I want to use the Ring Switcher.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a very simple way. Testing in Guest session. In the end is just about disabling conflicting key bindings of previous settings.